# Unable to use zoomcontrols in android camera preview

Tags: android, android-camera, preview, zooming

I am new to android programming. I am developing a simple application called magnifier which will use camera lens to zoom in and out the preview. But I am stuck with my code since zoom in and out are not working. below is my preview class and when I run the application on my phone, there is no error but zoom in and out are not working.Can someone please help me fix this error

```
class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {    
private static final String TAG = "Preview";

SurfaceHolder mHolder;
public Camera camera;
int currentZoomLevel = 0;
int maxZoomLevel = 0;
int MAX_ZOOM = 4;
Button buttonzoomin;
Button buttonzoomout;


Preview(Context context) {
    super(context);

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
    // to draw.
    camera = Camera.open();

    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

        camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {

            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {
                FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                try {
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format(
                            "/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    outStream.write(data);
                    outStream.close();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: "
                            + data.length);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                }
                Preview.this.invalidate();
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
    // Because the CameraDevice object is not a shared resource, it's very
    // important to release it when the activity is paused.
    //camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
    camera = null;
}




public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
    // the preview.

    final Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    buttonzoomin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonzoomin);
    buttonzoomout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonzoomout);

    // You need to choose the most appropriate previewSize for your app
    Camera.Size previewSize = previewSizes.get(0);

   Display display = ((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

    if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0)
    {
        parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.height, previewSize.width);                           
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    }

    if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_90)
    {
        parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);                           
    }

    if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_180)
    {
        parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.height, previewSize.width);               
    }

    if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270)
    {
        parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
    }


    if(parameters.isSmoothZoomSupported()){    
        buttonzoomin.setEnabled(true);
        buttonzoomout.setEnabled(true);
        maxZoomLevel = parameters.getMaxZoom();
            buttonzoomin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                        currentZoomLevel=currentZoomLevel + 1;
                        if(currentZoomLevel > maxZoomLevel)
                        {
                            currentZoomLevel = maxZoomLevel;;
                        }
                        //camera.startSmoothZoom(currentZoomLevel);
                        parameters.setZoom(currentZoomLevel);
                        camera.stopPreview();
                        camera.startPreview();
                        camera.setParameters(parameters);

                }
            });

        buttonzoomout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                        currentZoomLevel = currentZoomLevel-1;
                        if(currentZoomLevel < 0)
                        {
                            currentZoomLevel = 0;
                        }
                        //camera.startSmoothZoom(currentZoomLevel);
                        parameters.setZoom(currentZoomLevel);
                        camera.stopPreview();
                        camera.startPreview();
                        camera.setParameters(parameters);
                }
            });    
       }
     camera.setParameters(parameters);
     camera.startPreview(); }   
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) 
{
    super.draw(canvas);
    Paint p = new Paint(Color.RED);
    Log.d(TAG, "draw");
    canvas.drawText("PREVIEW", canvas.getWidth() / 2,
            canvas.getHeight() / 2, p);
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not using smooth zoom. Many devices do not necessarily support smooth zoom, and currently you have no backup case for when smooth zoom is not supported––For instance, your zoom in button is never enabled!